# Selenium with Google Chrome MacBook, Chrome quick quit issue after running the program

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, driver

I have been dealing with a problem using Selenium module in python on my macOS(intel),
The issue is when I run the code everything is fine, no errors, no warnnings, BUT the browser opens and after maybe 3 seconds it closes by itself and I don't know Why.
This is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# connect to google.com
s = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s,options=Options())
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Please Help :(

I was trying to control my Chrome app using python Selenium